# Which actor plays Thanos in the Avengers mid-credits scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, actors, the-avengers-2012

I know what characters are shown in the extra scene in the credits but I can't find a name for one of the actors. I know one is Alexis Denisof but it's the actor

> who plays Thanos

I need help with. Thanks.

Comment: You can ask a more explicit question using a spoiler tag to hide the spoilers, i.e. the character names.  The spoiler tag is to just put ">!" at the start of a new line in front of the spoiler text.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you're talking about the first post-credit scene.

From [“The Avengers” has two post-credit scenes, mystery actor revealed](http://www.ifc.com/fix/2012/05/the-avengers-post-credit-scenes):

> But while many just assumed that Thanos was entirely CGI, it turns out that he was actually played by an actor named [Damion Poitier](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1364280/).

He is listed as Man #1 at the [Avengers IMDB entry](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/fullcredits#cast).